# Using Tensorflow for multi-label classification

Tags: tensorflow, classification, loss

I have a multi-label classification problem with 5 labels. Is it correct if I have a my output layer to be of shape [n_samples, n_labels=5] and have the loss function as tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits? Or should I have the output layer in the shape of [n_samples, n_labels=5, 2] where 2 is to encode if each label is assigned to the sample or not?

Comment: How to do you plan to use the multilabel classifier?? Multilabel classifiers are quite different from multi class classifier. Tensorflow  has sigmoid_cross_entropy function too which is generally used for multi-label classification and then you either learn some kind of a threshold or use a constant threshold to select the labels for an instance.

Comment: Actually I am using tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits as this is the one that is suitable for multi-label and the softmax one is for multi-class problem. I edited my post.

Comment: The output layer should still be of shape `[n_samples, n_labels]`

Comment: So, then should I use threshold to decide to assign a label or not?

Comment: Yess.. You should be thresholding after the classifier finishes training

Answer (score -2):

I think the shape of output layer should be [n_samples, n_labels], and when you using tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits, make sure the label array is in the format of one-hot, another recommended interface is [tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/api_docs/python/functions_and_classes/shard4/tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits.md), which labels should be the entry of n_labels;